# Classification of Groups of orders < 8: Prove that a group G with order 1 is isomorphic to the empty set.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

At first, I attempted to do a proof by showing a homomorphism between the groups, then bijectivity:

First, let us define a function $f∶G \to \{0\}$ by $f(x) = 0$. Note that
$f(xy) = 0+0 = f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x, y \in G$. Thus, $f$ is a homomorphism. Suppose
for some $x \in G$, $f(x) = e_G$ then $0 = f(x) = e_G$, furthermore $e_G = x+0 = x+eG = x$
thus $f$ is injective. Let $x \in \{0\}$ and $a \in G$. Then set $x = a = 0 \in \{0\}$ thus $f$ is
surjective and consequently bijective. Thus, $G \cong \{0\}$.

Then I realized that I was approaching it completely incorrectly (and the proof itself is incorrect). So follows my second attempt after getting the hint that $G$ only has one element $\{e_G\}$:

First, let us define a function $f \colon G \to \{0\}$ by $f(x) = 0$. Note that since $\left| G \right| = 1$ then $G = \{e_G\}$.

Am I overthinking this and I could simply state that since there are the same amount of elements in both groups that they are consequently isomorphic?

*I'm more confused and lost than ever ... Clearly I'm not an expert by any means at Group Theory, so please, be gentle.

Comment: How can a group be isomorphic to the empty set? The empty set is not a group.

Answer (score 1):

In general, from two groups having the same number of elements, one cannot conclude that they are isomorphic. An example for this is $\mathbb{Z}_4$ the cyclic group of order $4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ the Klein-4-group.

However, in your case, since we know that every group has at least one element (the identity) i.e. the trivial group is a subgroup of $G$ and we know that $G$ has only one element, we can conclude that $\{e\}$ and $G$ coincide. Here $e$ denotes the identity element of a group.

If you want to have an explicit isomorphism between $G$ and $\{e\}$ then you can do this by $x \mapsto e$ for every $x \in G$.